# Write strings into database and display in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I have a list strings:

```
abc
def
xyz
```

I am writing code to insert each string (from first row to last row) to file by click a button. That means I need click three times on the button to insert all string to a file. After that, I have other button to display the data to gridview. Each row of gridview corresponds to each string such as

```
1. abc (1. is just index of gridview row)
2. def
3. xyz
```

For my task, I want to find a simple solution to do it by using android. I know that we can save it in sql or text file. What is simpler solution for my task? For saving in text file, how to distinguish between two strings in the file? If it is possible, could you give me the code? thanks

This is my solution for wring text file

```
String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String filename=filepath+"/" + FOLDER +  "/" + "list.txt"   ;   
FileOutputStream fop = null;
File file = null;

try {
    file =new File(filename);
    fop=new FileOutputStream(file,true);
    // if file doesn't exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    // get the content in bytes
    byte[] contentInBytes = filecontent.getBytes();

    fop.write(contentInBytes);
    fop.flush();
    fop.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, output is `abcdefxyz`. It is very difficult to classify them.

Comment: A little notice. Use a recyclerview. Its much better than gridview

Comment: i suggest using sqlite. also using recyclerview will be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have

```
string[] items={abc,def,xyz};
```

**writing to file**

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("filename.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
   for(String data : items)
   {
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
   }
        outputStreamWriter.close();
```

Reading from File

```
 InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("filename.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                data.Add(receiveString);
            }

            inputStream.close();
```

in Grid View Adpater use `data` ArrayList

Comment: Thank rajan ks. However, I am working in a class which is TestThread extends Thread. How to use your function openFileOutput?